# Low level keyboard hook

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hook, drivers

I just bought a new keyboard, and I'm interested in tracking exactly how many keypresses/strokes I make during the entire life of the keyboard. (I would want to just record keyUp, as I don't care about repeats)

I've been googling around for the best way to do this,  but I don't even know what approach to take, so I'm having trouble searching intelligently.
Also, the only language I've really worked with is C#.  Haven't done anything with C/C++ or WinAPI

Is it difficult to modify the Win 7 drivers directly? 
I do want to be able to record keystrokes from the moment the computer boots,  but this may not be easily done.
I would prefer to use an existing driver or hook,  as I really don't care to get into learning device drivers right now.

I've looked briefly at Ctrl2Cap,  but I don't know how to modify something like that to suit my case.

Other questions I looked at,

- [Writing a keyboard device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527707/writing-a-keyboard-device-driver)
- [Low level keyboard Hook not at UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054839/low-level-keyboard-hook-not-at-ui-thread)

This one indicates writing a USB Filter driver may work,  but I have no clue where to start on that.
[Disabling the keyboard in windows c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214648/disabling-the-keyboard-in-windows-c)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to go the driver route, which is not for the faint of heart. You can use use a low level keyboard hook which will work fine from .NET.

I did a quick bing and found the following on codeplex 
http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

It should get you going

Comment: This is the best answer, but be aware that virtually all anti-virus software will identify any program with a keyboard hook as malware and quarantine it.  You'll have to manually exclude it from being quarantined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that you need to use **Kernel Level Keylogger**. It's grabs the keystrokes before the operating system takes effects and this one 99% invisible for detection techniques. Then you can grab the Windows Log On screen typed things like password/username etc.

@ChrisTaylor's key logger not work for WinLog-on Screen I reckon. If you can install the keyboard driver filter before the system keyboard device driver take a action you can handle windows user login screen also. But In order to install this driver level key hook you need to have administrator privileges.

I found [Unix](https://github.com/AishaNair/Key-Logger) and [Windows Keyloggers](https://github.com/akayn/kbMon) from Github. Free to play with this https://www.adlice.com/kernelmode-rootkits-part-3-kernel-filters/  and have fun!

Answer (score -2):

That, what you want is dangerous!
With the same code everyone can create keylogger* 
But if you not a virus creator then I recommend you to search "hotkeying in  C/C++" or something like that and hook keyboard with hotkeys!
I have written HotKey Maker in VB6 which can make hotkey from every button of keyboard.
But I really not interested in viruses :)
Good Luck !

*Virus which hooks your keyboard and send all what you wrote in keyboard to Virus owner

Comment: Yes, it's one way to make a keylogger but there's nothing dangerous about it.

Comment: Is dangerous, because keyboard hook can easily be caught with many antiviruses. And then they can simply look where is going info from keylogger , and ... find you :) I think you willn't want to create virus after this ;)

Comment: @Searush  probably means it's dangerous to your health if you get caught using a keylogger in a nefarious way, and he's not wrong.  But keylogger code *of itself*  is not dangerous.